# Reliable clipboard manager

Tags: 11.04, clipboard, clipboard-manager

There are many clipboard managers available.

The first one I used, I found out if messes clipboard history if clipboard contents was multiline - which I found to be very lame and naive

Second one which I use now is also faulty - I wanted recent clipboard content and I found it's not present in history. I deliberately copied piece of text and text is not copied in history so I can't reuse it, although if I select edit clipboard I find the contents that I just copied

Can someone with more experience suggest **reliable** clipboard manager, with panel icon or indicator icon feature?

Comment: Parcellite, Glipper, Pastie, Klipper and Glippy  Have you tried them all?

Comment: I'm asking if experienced users have tried them, (used them for longer period) so I (and potentially others) don't have to spend time to test all of them.

Comment: OK. they all have worked for me, but found them redundant for the use i gave to them, so i uninstalled them.

Comment: Both faulty I mentioned are in your list ;)

Comment: You should mention which ones are so they are no longer mentioned in further responses

Comment: Well I hope not. I'll mention them later

Comment: There would also be Diodon (https://launchpad.net/diodon). However I suppose it would be a good idea when you find a bug in one of the clipboard manager that you file a bug. Or are there any bug filed already you could point us too?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tried Glipper and Parcellite, because they were on the repos. I ended using Diodon because neither of them worked well for me. One of them (I don't remember know which) had a bug that made it copy every single letter from a selection to the clipboard:

If I selected "foo bar" from left to right, I would get 
"f"
"fo"
"foo"
"foo "
"foo b"
etc

in the clipboard.

I was using Diodon in 11.04 and I got back to it, even via a third PPA, in 11.10. It works great.

Comment: OK, thanks for answering. I didn't try Diodon, as I'm currently happy with Glippy, and as other commenter also suggested it, I'll mark your answer as accepted

Answer (score 3):

I first installed two managers: **Anamnesis** and **Glippy**

**Anamnesis** had some interesting features, but I dislike it UI window implementation

Then I used **Glippy**, for a week now, without any issue, and I now recommend it to others who didn't have a chance to try various clipboard managers

---

To provide promised information:
first one (which makes mess from multiline clipboard) is **Glipper**
second one (which stalls occasionally, and needs clipboard reset to continue working) is **Pastie**

Answer (score 1):

This is one of the best indicator-style applications named [CopyQ](http://sourceforge.net/projects/copyq/). It is not in Software center, hence a download link. Runs great in Ubuntu 14.10 so I am surprised nobody have mentioned it.

[image]

[image]

- Supports Windows, OS X and Linux.
- Store text, HTML, images and any other custom format.
- Customize tray menu.
- Save items in new tabs (and groups).
- Quickly browse through items (fast navigation, filtering with matched text highlighting).
- Sort items, create new, remove, copy/paste to different tab.
- Variety of system-wide shortcuts (e.g. show main window or tray, edit clipboard, copy next/previous item, paste as plain text).
- Immediately paste to focused window from tray or main window.
- Fully customizable appearance (colors, fonts, transparency).
- Add notes to items.
- Advanced command-line interface and scripting.
- Ignore clipboard copied from some windows or containing some text.

Answer (score 0):

You can check [Keepboard](http://sourceforge.net/projects/keepboard/). It's been around for a few years and people were not complaining about its stability...